# How to make height of boxes same for every article so there is no white space

Tags: jquery, html, css, whitespace, article

I would like to make same height of the box for every article. When I write more text, box will be higher which is not what I want. Is there any way to achieve this?

http://michalurban.cz/rybicky/

Here is the problem marked on image:
[image: problem with white space]

Comment: Edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste ALL the code that you have tried. This isn't a free code writing service. You have to help

Comment: Ditto to the above. But, there's at least two ways to do it 1. Set a min height on each container and limit content so they are all the same 2. Use an Equalise javascript system that measures all containers and applies the tallest height to all of them.

Comment: Yeah try a min-height of 215px on the nabuzeni class.

Comment: i'm not sure about min-height... if there is enough text the height could still exceed 215px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can find the largest height of all the elements and apply that height to all of them.

```js
// @param $elements - a jQuery object of the elements you want the same height
function setHeightsToLargest($elements) {
  var largest = 0;
  $elements.each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height(); 
    if (h > largest) {
      largest = h;
    }
  });
  $elements.height(largest);
}

setHeightsToLargest($('article'));
```

```css
article {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <p>
    V této novince si představíme nádherný aquascape, který vytvořil 29letý Ryan Thang To. Aquascaping je v podstatě naaranžování kamenů, rostlin, substrátu, kořenů a jiných věcí v akváriu tak, že vznikne esteticky příjemná přírodní podívaná.
  </p>
</article>
<article>
  <p>
    V thajském Bangkoku jsme mohli v minulosti najít uvnitř jednoho z opuštěných obchodních center obří nádrž plnou Koi a sumců. Proč právě v obchodním centru a&nbsp;jak se tam dostali?
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. :)